# 'Terminal close -- query aborted' even after running with nohup and &

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, unix, sh

I am running a script using `nohup sh loader_in_loop.sh &`

my assumption is the job would run in background without interruptions.

loader_in_loop.sh has a loop that runs some DB long operations for each loop element.

When its running this step (mysql schema_one < /storage/staging/$filename) for one of the loop element, it is failing with 'Terminal close -- query aborted' error..

But the job runs in background picking next element in loop.

So, I assume its failing when the terminal is frozen after few minutes, but nohup and & should handle this situation, but they are not.

Can someone please suggest on what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: searching for the error message led me to https://www.reddit.com/r/devops/comments/44r27m/job_interrupted_when_terminal_is_closed/